# Facebook Customer Chat missing Close Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-customer-chat

I have implement the FB Customer Chat on a website and working ok. The issue i am having is that there is no obvious way to close the dialog (i.e having an (x) button) if the user does not need the chat dialog.

The problem only applies to desktop. In mobile the dialog has the x (close) button as it should. What am i missing?

This is how it looks on deskop without the close button.

[image: fb customer chat]

Answer (score 0):

If your visitor to your site using a desktop, clicks on the FB widget the chat box will disappear.

Comment: I am aware of this. But as noted in my question i need an obvious way for the users. The vast majority of users do not understand that in order to close the chat you can press on FB Messenger Logo. We are working on a modification to use JS and some CSS to change the Messenger Logo with an "X" button when it's open. This at least could make users to find easier how to close the chat.